# Answer not showing up in (recent) inbox

Tags: feature-request, bug

How is it possible for an [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16619/11449) to your [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16610/11449) not to show up in your *recent* StackExchange inbox on the website

[image]

, but only in your *all items inbox*:

[image]

?

That is, the question I received "16 hours ago" is supposed to be inbetween the messages where the red arrow points in the first screenshot.

If this is not a bug, then I would suggest a change to this mechanism such that your recent messages inbox receives **all answers**.

If there is a valid reason for not changing this (hypothetically non-bug/intended) mechanism then I would like to hear it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If there is a valid reason for not changing this" ... well, it is likely that you will visit the post and then check other answers for updates as well, thus spotting other new answers as well. Also, I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign): only the latest of each type of notification for a given post is retained once read, to reduce clutter in a very frequently used tool. After all, as you noticed, the user activities page retains all of them in case you do want to see it.

For example, my inbox now contains one entry for three comments I received on some post, but earlier, when it was unread, there were three separate entries. The older ones of those were removed from the inbox after I checked the inbox once.

So, it's possible that when you checked the inbox the first time after the newest answer was posted, you didn't notice the entry for the older answer, and when you checked it again, that entry was deleted since it looked like you have already read that notification entry.

Comment: *For example, my inbox now contains one entry for three comments I received on some post, but earlier, when it was unread, there were three separate entries. The older ones of those were removed from the inbox after I checked the inbox once.* Wow! :) On a further consideration, I think this mechanism as been thought through very well. The key idea that I like about it is that *The older ones of those were removed from the inbox after I checked the inbox once.* It is implemented to such sophistication, that the user doesn't even *notice* its working merits (unless your pedantic).

Comment: Altough good arguments exist on both sides, I now agree with the status quo.